# Can I add state property values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add properties in my state object? When I try to add the values, I get NaN for the total.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {

  value1: 40,
  value2: 60,  
  total: this.value1 + this.value2

  }
}
```

No issues when compiling but the code renders: 40 + 60 = NaN

```
<p>{`${this.state.value1} + ${this.state.value2} = ${this.state.total}`}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because the definition of the state is not yet finished. So `this.state` will be undefined still, and `this.value1` doesn't make sense because these aren't values of the object, but of the state contained within it. You'll need to move the `total` calculation to the constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value1: 40,
    value2: 60,  
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.total = this.state.value1 + this.state.value2;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter-setter statements. These statements work after class initialize, therefore the references in total value doesn't give undefined and you don't get NaN (undefined + undefined = NaN).

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        value1: 40,
        value2: 60,  
        get total() {
            return this.value1 + this.value2;
        }
    }
}
```